# text color of code

Tags: discussion

I see there is a text color inconsistence. Some are well formatted with blue color and some are plain text color. like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607378/how-to-select-only-the-last-value-in-a-query-in-mysql) two are giving same answer and one is formatted with color and other not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't add `<!-- language: lang-sql -->` in my answer. The post is tagged with [php](/questions/tagged/php), [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) and [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) that's why it couldn't decide which language highlights should be used. I just edited the posts.

Also, now I removed the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag (as the question is not related to PHP). So other user's answer is also showing correct highlighting.

Comment: Thanks, I should have known that earlier.